# Issue while Generating Primary Key in JPA2.0 and Database DB2

Tags: java, jpa, db2, openjpa

```
public class A implements Serializable {

/** The strategic_ goal_ key. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "A_KEY")
private String A_KEY;
}
```

While I try to Save this Object expecting a primary key to be generated by JPA am getting the below Error .

```
  Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.
 ReportingSQLException:  "CGSP.OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE" 
is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.52.95 {prepstmnt 1791912654 
SELECT SEQUENCE_VALUE 
FROM CGSP.OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE 
WHERE ID = ? FOR READ ONLY WITH RS USE AND KEEP UPDATE LOCKS 
[params=(int) 0]} [code=-204, state=42704]
```

Any suggestions on the above as to how to auto-generate the Primary Key value

Comment: As the error message says, the table CGSP.OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE is missing. Not knowing anything about OpenJPA I'd venture to guess that it was not properly installed or configured.

Comment: What OS is your DB2 server running under? What are your connection string settings?

Comment: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704 means "Object does not exist" in IBM DB2 speak.  So either that table doesn't exist or this user doesn't have read permission to it if does exist.